# Heroku: “Process exited with status 127” after deploying python Django App

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, django-templates

After deploying the app on Heroku and running it, it shows an error like this:

> **Application error**
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details.

And when I check the logs, it shows:

> 2018-03-30T07:25:13.273255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 
>  2018-03-30T07:25:14.757951+00:00 heroku[router]:
>   at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=protected-journey-42490.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=fdaf6efd-b490-4848-8f55-f583f1fc6b50 fwd="125.16.236.158"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
>   2018-03-30T07:25:15.888944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=protected-journey-42490.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=7cdefbb6-e1a0-42bf-bb4d-0deed69f9c61 fwd="125.16.236.158"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Here's the reference link of my repository : **[pages_project](https://bitbucket.org/amitmeel/pages_projectr/src/master/)**

Comment: Can you please describe the exact process. Also never upload secret key and db to bitbucket. Heroku recommend using decouple and environment variable

Comment: @VipinMohan after successfully deployed my code on Heroku when i run the command : Heroku open it shows the above described error. I dont understand why my app is crashed again and again.

Comment: @VipinMohan also when i run it on local server that is provided by django itself..its working fine for me.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html  use this, i deployed following this tutorial, and always check heroku logs, and use git gui, it is helpful, in locating errors

Comment: which database did you use, heroku does not support sqlite, you should use postgres.

Comment: @VipinMohan by default when you are not provide any database to Django ,then it will automatically uses sqlite.

Comment: @VipinMohan Ok I will try this tutorial..thankx

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `gunicorn` then add it in `requitements.txt` file